# Net::SMTPAuthenticationError exception with capistrano and puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mailgun

I deployed my server with capistrano 3 and runs in puma.

Everyhting works well except mailing.

When I tried to send an email via webform, I got the following exception.

However, I can sucessfully send mail under `rails console`.

There is no typo on password or api key, because I sent mails via the console sucessfully

Any suggestion to get more debug information, I don't know how to get further information.

```
I, [2015-08-27T05:47:07.691835 #14686]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2627ms
F, [2015-08-27T05:47:07.693123 #14686] FATAL -- :
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535 5.7.0 Mailgun is not loving your login or password
):
```